# Drupal Commerce Product Attributes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am trying, so far unsucessfully to add product attributes to my drupal commerce store.

I have created a product display which displays my title, price, and general product, then a list of products that are each a different color

My product display references my "product reference" and when creating a new display, I am givin the form as expected for title, body, and I can select all my colors, however once saved, there is no drop down for the user to select colors and it always just defaults to whatever color was the first selected when creating the product display

Any help, or tips would be appreciated

Comment: In the color field configuration did you check "Use this field as attribute" ?

Answer (score 0):

For choosing colors, can help module [Commerce Fancy Attributes](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes)